# sinon stub with es6-promisified object

Tags: javascript, testing, ecmascript-6, sinon, es6-promise

Ok my setup is as follows:
Using node 6.2, es6-promisify, sinon, sinon-as-promised, and babel to transpile support for es6 import/export.

My code under test looks something like this:

```
const client = restify.createJsonClient({
    url: 'http://www.example.com'
});
export let get = promisify(client.get, {thisArg: client, multiArgs: true});

export default function* () {
    yield get('/some/path');
}
```

And then in my test file I have something like this:

```
import * as m from mymodule;
it('should fail', function(done) {
    let stub = sinon.stub(m, 'get').rejects('i failed');
    client.get('/endpoint/that/leads/to/mymodule/call', function(err, req, res, data) {
        stub.called.should.be.eql(true); // assertion fails!!
        done();
    }
});
```

I've also tried stubbing the original client.get call, and that doesn't work either. The only thing I've gotten to work is promisifying on the fly with each call, and stubbing the original client.get, which seems pretty lame. E.g.:

```
export const client = restify.createJsonClient({
    url: 'http://www.example.com'
});
function get() {
    return promisify(client.get, {thisArg: client, multiArgs: true});
}

export default function* () {
    yield get('/some/path');
}
```

And test code doing this:

```
import {module_client} from mymodule;
it('should fail', function(done) {
    let stub = sinon.stub(module_client, 'get').yields('i failed');
    client.get('/endpoint/that/leads/to/mymodule/call', function(err, req, res, data) {
        stub.called.should.be.eql(true); // assertion succeeds
        done();
    }
});
```

And so the question, if it's not completely obvious, is why does my original code not work? And is there a way to make the stub work without promisifying the original restify each time (e.g. how do other people get this sort of thing working)?

EDIT:

Current code looks like this:

```
const client = restify.createJsonClient({
    url: 'http://www.example.com'
});

export let get = promisify(client.get, {thisArg: client, multiArgs: true});

export default function*() {
    try {
        console.log(exports.get); // <= a large sinon stub object, I'll post that below
        yield exports.get(); // <= throws here, "exports.get is not a function"
    }
    catch(ex) {
        log.error('got an error', ex);
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

The console.log prints the following:

```
{ [Function: proxy]
  isSinonProxy: true,
  reset: [Function],
  invoke: [Function: invoke],
  named: [Function: named],
  getCall: [Function: getCall],
  getCalls: [Function],
  calledBefore: [Function: calledBefore],
  calledAfter: [Function: calledAfter],
  withArgs: [Function],
  matches: [Function],
  printf: [Function],
  calledOn: [Function],
  alwaysCalledOn: [Function],
  calledWith: [Function],
  calledWithMatch: [Function],
  alwaysCalledWith: [Function],
  ....
```

EDIT2:

And FWIW, the babel generated code is producing this:

```
let get = exports.get = (0, _es6Promisify2.default)(client.get, { thisArg: client, multiArgs: true });
```

EDIT3:

Ok super weird. I changed my source to do this instead:

```
const client = restify.createJsonClient({
    url: 'http://www.example.com'
});

export let get = promisify(client.get, {thisArg: client, multiArgs: true});

export default function*() {
    try {
        let thePromise = exports.get(); // e.g. call exports.get on separate line from the yield
        yield thePromise; // and the throw now says 'undefined is not a function'. I should note that in both cases, the stack trace shows the error on node_modules/co/index.js at line 65.
    }
    catch(ex) {
        log.error('got an error', ex);
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Comment: `get()` isn't exported so `module_client.get()` is undefined in your test code. But even if it were exported, there are still issues that are caused by ES6 (at least, I think). I'll see if I can write is up as an answer.

Comment: if you mean 'get' isn't being exported in the second example, you're right, I do have an error there. what I meant was, the original restify.client is exported as module_client. And I'm stubbing that. Which works.

Comment: Oh sorry, of course it is! My answer should still apply to the first case, the second case works around it by promisifying at runtime instead of at import time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem ultimately has to do with how ES6 import/exports work, and specifically, how they make your code look better *but* prevent easy spying/stubbing.

Take this example module:

```
// my-module.js
function someFunction() {
  console.log('original');
};

export let get = someFunction;

export default function() {
  get();
};
```

A test case for that code could look like this:

```
import * as sinon from 'sinon';
import * as should from 'should';
import setup, * as myModule from './my-module';

it('should call get()', () => {
  let stub = sinon.stub(myModule, 'get');
  setup();
  stub.called.should.eql(true);
});
```

You'll see that the original `get()` gets called, and not the stub. This is because in the module, `get` is a local (to the module) reference. Sinon is stubbing *another* reference to the same function, in the exported object.

To make this work, instead of using a local reference in the module, you need to use the one in the exported object:

```
export default function() {
  exports.get();
};
```

Which, alas, makes for uglier code.

Comment: So I did as you said, which does make sense. But I get another error. In the code under test, it throws where I call exports.get saying "exports.get is not a function". If I do console.log on exports.get just prior to the call, it shows that it's an object--the sinon stub object. I can paste it into my question but the object is pretty large.

Comment: I edited my answer so the code mimics your first example a bit more.

Comment: OK so the exports.get is the right object, it's the sinon stub proxy object. So my confusion is why it's now crashing saying exports.get isn't a function. I mean, it's _not_ a function, it's a proxy. But its no different than what sinon is doing elsewhere in my code. So...?

Comment: @Kevin check out [this gist](https://gist.github.com/robertklep/1715cdc7801394f901b8a1da07ec5edf). That fails as well, with a similar error. It looks like yielding a Sinon stub is causing the error. Still no clue why, but at least it's reproducable.

Comment: well that's at least reassuring, that it can be reproduced. So the thing is, I don't think it's yielding a sinon stub. It's calling a function (exports.get) which returns a promise. And co knows how to deal with yielded promises (or, I think, thenables in general). So the fact that it's saying "exports.get is not a function", to me means, that nothing ever got yielded. Because it needs to evaluate the function and produce a result (the promise) before the function gets suspended by yield.

Comment: If I replace the stub with a spy in my test case, it works, so that's not the issue either. You are still using `sinon-as-promised` in your test and not `sinon.stub(...).yields()`, right?

Comment: yes Im using `sinon-as-promised`, so in my test I'm doing `sinon.stub(...).resolves({},{},{});`

Comment: I updated the question with another edit. It gets even more strange.

Comment: It's beginning to look like an interaction issue between the various transpiler/conversion modules and Sinon :-(

Comment: I'll mark your answer as correct since you at least resolved the first part of the question. I don't think there's much I can do about the second part...Thanks!