# Node.js sinon test async.js waterfall function

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, asynchronous, sinon, async.js

Consider the following scenario:

```
function MyClass() { ... }
MyClass.prototype.funcToTest = function() {
    varl self = this;
    async.waterfall([
        async.apply(self.a.func.bind(self.a), 5, 'hi'),
        function(result, callback) {
            ...
            // I want to test this function
            // I can't move it to separate function due to closure variables used
        }
    ], function(err, result) {
           ...
        }
    );
}

module.exports = MyClass;
```

How would I go about testing the second function in the task array supplied to `async.waterfall()` ? 
 I've done the following but it doesn't work:

```
var MyClass = require('my-class;);
var stub = sinon.stub();
stub.yields(null, [1, 2, 3]);
var myClassIsntance = {
    a: {
        func: stub
    }
};
MyClass.prototype.funcToTest.call(myClassIsntance);
```

but the second function is not being called and I'm not sure why. If I'm not mistaken `async.waterfall()` should call **at-least** its first task immediately, and I use sinon's `yields()` method so it will call the second task immediately after but it doesn't seem to work. My guess is that there's some asynchronous operation going behind the scene stalling the execution of the second task that I'm not aware of. I even tried use sinon`s fake timer after calling `funcToTest()` to see if the second task will be called after that, but it didn't work.

Comment: `otherFunc` doesn't take a callback, so the non-stubbed code wouldn't be working to begin with. If you want to stub a function that's exported from a module and want to use that function inside the module as well, you need to call it as `exports.otherFunc` (in `funcToTest`), otherwise Sinon can't stub it. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37488052/893780) explains why (the answer deals with ES6 import/export, but the same applied to regular Node modules).

Comment: @robertklep I think I over-simplified my illustration, it's not taken directly from my code because it's much more complex, but `otherFunc()` is basically an object function which I can stub so I don't think it's the second problem you mentioned causing my problem. About the first problem, I took a look at my code and I see that the next function (and all others) are actually extracting the callback from arguments with some logic done. Maybe this causing the `yields()` method not work properly because the callback is not explicitly passed but extracted from arguments ? If so, what can I do ?

Comment: Well, the issue isn't so much being able to stub it (that'll work just fine), the issue is getting `funcToTest` to actually _call_ the stub. Even though it may sound trivial (_"it's calling `otherFunc`, and I can stub `otherFunc`, so it should work"_), it's not :) I don't think `yields` is the issue, because when the stub would get called, it would look for a function argument, basically doing the same as what you're describing.

Comment: @robertklep I've edited the original example to better reflect what's going on and what I've talked about. Does the thing you said still apply ? Because just by debugging the test and hovering over `self.a.func()` I can see it got stubbed, because it's a proxy method sinon made.

Comment: I've put your code [in a standalone gist](https://gist.github.com/robertklep/37a2e95a31882d3b3b3492bb277dea85), and it seems to be working just fine (it prints _"GOT HERE [ 1, 2, 3 ]"_, as expected).

Comment: @robertklep well when I debug it, it just seem to get to the `async.waterfall()` call it and skip to the end of the function, I don't see it getting to the second task. I've tried to assert that `self.a.func()` was called but it failed, any suggestions ?

Comment: Are you talking about my standalone code, or your own?

Comment: @robertklep my own, although I just noticed the problem, left over code that I used to stub the `async.waterfall()`, removed it, everything works fine now :)